# ADuser not adding samAccountName after changing Variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Thanks in advance !

I have made a script and in this script, I add users from excel to AD and it works for 99% but I need to make 1 change to it but when I do that it gives me errors.

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\admin.kln\Documents\Project\BOSAN_USERS.csv |foreach{

#All strings of variables you need out of excel
$Firstname = $_.Firstname
$Lastname = $_."Last Name"
$Displayname = $_."Display Name"
$Extraname = $_."Display Name"
$Logonname = $_."Logon Name"
$Accountpassword = $_.AccountPassword
$Description = $_.Description
$Jobtitle = $_."Job Title"
$Department = $_.Department
$Company = $_.Company
$Telephonenumber = $_.TelephoneNumber
$Mobilenumber = $_."Mobile number"
$Street = $_.Street
$PObox = $_."P.O. Box"
$City = $_.City
$State = $_."State / Province"
$Zip = $_.Zip
$Country = $_.Country
$Manager = $_.Manager
$ProxyEmail = $_."Proxy Address + Email(SMTP)"
$ProxyAdress = $_."Proxy Addresss(smpt)"
$ProxySip = $_."Proxy address (SIP)"
$Final = (($_.Firstname.ToLower().Substring(0,1)) + '.' + ($_."Last name".ToLower()))

#int
$i = 1
$u = 1
$o = 1
#Check if its over 18 chars if it is it will be shortened
if ($Displayname.Length -gt 18) { $Displayname = $Displayname.Substring(0,18) }
if ($Extraname.Length -gt 18) { $Extraname = $Extraname.Substring(0,18) }

try
    {
        while (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Extraname})
        {
            Write-Warning "Er bestaat al een account met de naam $Extraname"
            $Extraname = $Displayname + [string]$i
            $i++
            
            $Logonname = $Logonname + [string]$o
            $o++

            $Final = (($_.Firstname.ToLower().Substring(0,1)) + '.' + ($_."Last Name".ToLower()))
            $Final = $Final + [string]$u
            $u++
        }
    }
catch{}
finally
        {

            $Logonname = $Logonname -replace ' ',''
            $Final = $Final -replace ' ',''
            echo $Final
            New-ADUser -Path "ou=Users,ou=NLHKH,dc=CONTOSO,dc=com" `
            -SamAccountName $Extraname `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Name $Extraname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -DisplayName $Extraname `
            -UserPrincipalName $Final `
            -accountpassword(ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -force) `
            -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
            -Description $Description `
            -Title $Jobtitle `
            -Department $Department `
            -Company $Company `
            -MobilePhone $Mobilenumber `
            -StreetAddress $Street `
            -City $City `
            -State $State `
            -PostalCode $Zip `
            -POBOX $PObox 
            

        }
}
```

As you can see it should work like this but I need to change -SamAccountName to $final or at least to the same Variable as $Final. But that won't do.

[image: this is how it counts]

Comment: What is the change you need to make and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: By the -new Aduser I need to change -samaccountname to ```$Final``` or a Variable of ```$Final``` but when I do the first time it says for some of them ```The name provided is not a properly formed account name``` and the second time i run it it says for the rest which have been added the first time ```The specified account already exists``` but in the code it shouldn't be able to happen. It doesnt even happen to the UPN which has the same variable.

Comment: Some background would be good too.  Looks like you are trying to find a good account name to use for a new user, but maybe you can clarify.

Comment: It increments 1, 2, 3 and I have made it so they can't hit the 20 char limit because it will start at 18. The foreach loop will loop until the last name in the excel sheet

Comment: I have an appointment for my internship. I need to fill an AD out of excel with PowerShell and the details are clasified.

Comment: i edited the post as you can see it does appen to "2" and also if i dont length check before the try loop(it always happens in the FOREACH loop) it doesn't go INTO the loop itself so it gives errors the name isn't unique forest wide UPN problem.

Comment: You are taking the DisplayName property from the CSV file as base to create a unique SamAccountName. This can lead to various problems if you don't abide by the [rules](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11216.active-directory-requirements-for-creating-objects.aspx#Objects_with_sAMAccountName_Attribute) and remove all invalid characters from it first.

Comment: I deleted those comments.  I see it...

Comment: Also, how do users log in to the domain in your environment? UPN? SamAccountName? You seem to just test for a unique SamAccountName, but do not check if the UPN is unique. Also, Why is there also a `$Logonname` you keep incrementing, when it is never used? (same for the ProxyAddresses)

Comment: I have used -replace " [ ] : ; | = + * ? < > / \ , which would remove the invalid chars but there still seems to be a problem.

Comment: Also ```r.
New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name``` seems to be an empty Last name which will get an error

Comment: No, `$Logonname` is a dummy in your script. It is not used in any of the attributes for the new user. Also, a UserPrincipalName should be in [internet format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats#user-principal-name) and in your case it is not.

Comment: I see now... can you explain the UPN?

Comment: ```#-mail $ProxyEmail `
            #-co $Country `
            #-telephoneNumber $Telephonenumber `

            #-Manager $Manager `
            #-proxyAddresses $ProxyEmail + $ProxyAdress + $ProxySip ``` this is also on the end of my code but NONE of those work they all get an error~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ this under the first part. It's like they dont exist but i looked it up in AD and these are the correct names for it. Any help with this aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would change quite a lot of your script.

First of all, you need two loops to figure out if

1. you get a valid unique SamAccountName
2. you get a valid unique UserPrincipalName

The ProxyAddresses need extra care aswell. You need to create an array of the 3 Proxy* fields in the CSV and add that with parameter `OtherAttributes`.
Mind that his will not accept a 'normal' array and that it needs to be cast with `[string[]]` to form a **strongly typed** string array.

Finally, use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for the `New-ADUser` cmdlet to get rid of those nasty backticks.

Something like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\admin.kln\Documents\Project\BOSAN_USERS.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # unused fields in the CSV:
    # $Logonname = $_."Logon Name"
    # $Country = $_.Country
    # $Manager = $_.Manager

    # construct a SamAccountName from the DisplayName in the CSV
    # replace all invalid characters and cut off anything over 20 characters
    $SamAccountName = $_."Display Name" -replace '[\x00-\x20"[\]:;|=+*?<>/,@\s]'
    if ($SamAccountName.Length -gt 20) { $SamAccountName = $SamAccountName.Substring(0, 20) }
    $temp = $SamAccountName
    # enter an endless loop to test if that user with that SamAccountName already exists
    $i = 1
    while ($true) {
        $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SamAccountName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # if a user with that SamAccountName does not yet exist, we can break out of the loop
        if (!$user) { break }

        # create a new SamAccountName to test
        while (($temp + $i).Length -gt 20) { 
            $temp = $temp.Substring(0, $temp.Length - 1) 
        }
        $SamAccountName = '{0}{1}' -f $temp, $i
        $i++
    }

    # since your UPN uses a different format than 'SamAccountName@CONTOSO.com', 
    # start another loop to make sure that too is unique
    # CHANGE @CONTOSO.com TO THE REAL DOMAIN NAME
    $UserPrincipalName = '{0}.{1}@CONTOSO.com' -f $_.Firstname.Substring(0,1).ToLower(), $_."Last name".ToLower()
    $i = 1
    while ($true) {
        $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$UserPrincipalName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # if a user with that UserPrincipalName does not yet exist, we can break out of the loop
        if (!$user) { break }

        # create a new UserPrincipalName by adding a sequence number to test
        $UserPrincipalName = '{0}.{1}{2}@CONTOSO.com' -f $_.Firstname.Substring(0,1).ToLower(), $_."Last name".ToLower(), $i
        $i++
    }

    # next, create an array of the Proxy Addresses. Watch the spelling in the CSV headers!
    $ProxyAddresses = ('SMTP:{0}' -f ($_."Proxy Address + Email(SMTP)" -replace '^SMTP:')),
                      ('smtp:{0}' -f ($_."Proxy Address(smpt)" -replace '^smtp:')),
                      ('SIP:{0}'  -f ($_."Proxy address (SIP)" -replace '^SIP:'))

    # now that we have unique names and a ProxyAddresses array, we can create the user
    $NewUserParms = @{
        'SamAccountName'        = $SamAccountName
        'Name'                  = ('{0} {1}' -f $_.FirstName, $_."Last Name").Trim()
        'DisplayName'           = $_."Display Name"
        'UserPrincipalName'     = $UserPrincipalName
        'GivenName'             = $_.FirstName
        'Surname'               = $_."Last Name"
        'Description'           = $_.Description
        'Title'                 = $_."Job Title"
        'Department'            = $_.Department
        'Company'               = $_.Company
        'AccountPassword'       = ConvertTo-SecureString $_.AccountPassword -AsPlainText -Force
        'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $true
        'Enabled'               = $true
        'OfficePhone'           = $_.TelephoneNumber
        'MobilePhone'           = $_."Mobile number"
        'StreetAddress'         = $_.Street
        'City'                  = $_.City
        'State'                 = $_."State / Province"
        'PostalCode'            = $_.Zip
        'POBox'                 = $_."P.O. Box"
        'EmailAddress'          = $_."Proxy Address + Email(SMTP)" -replace '^SMTP:'
        'Path'                  = "OU=Users,OU=NLHKH,DC=CONTOSO,DC=com"
        # ProxyAddresses needs cast to [string[]]
        'OtherAttributes'       = @{'proxyAddresses' = [string[]]$ProxyAddresses}  

        # add other properties to set from the CSV here if needed.
        # make sure you get the parameter data types correct and always check here:
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=win10-ps#parameters
        # switch parameters for the cmdlet can also be entered with a value $false or $true
    }

    try {
        # '-ErrorAction Stop' ensures that also non-terminating errors get handled in the catch block
        New-ADUser @NewUserParms -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        # something bad happened. Change 'Write-Warning' into 'throw' if you want your script to exit here
        # inside a catch block, the '$_' automatic variable represents the actual exception object.
        Write-Warning "Could not create account $username. $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I still get the error `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string` and ---------- is below the AccountPassword. And it gives the warning that it could'nt create the account. Can't validate argument on parameter 'name'

Comment: Also removed AccountPassword to check if the rest works but it does this `WARNING: Could not create account . The specified value already exists` at the first second and third time and so on

Comment: I do have the AccountPassword empty so that should be about right but then it will never add?